# CSS Menu - active link

Tags: html, css

using this CSS code, how can i make it so there is an active/current class?

```
#cssmenu *{
    z-index: 999
}
#cssmenu ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center; }
#cssmenu li { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#cssmenu a { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#cssmenu ul {list-style: none;}
#cssmenu a {text-decoration: none;}
#cssmenu {height: 50px; background-color: #f36f25; box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 16px 20px;
-webkit-transition: color .15s;
   -moz-transition: color .15s;
     -o-transition: color .15s;
        transition: color .15s;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {color: #ffffff; background-color:#666666; }
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    padding: 16px 0 20px 0;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -90px;
    width: 180px;
-webkit-transition: all .3s .1s;
   -moz-transition: all .3s .1s;
     -o-transition: all .3s .1s;
        transition: all .3s .1s;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 50px;
    visibility: visible;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul:before{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    border-color: transparent transparent rgb(250,250,250) transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul > li { position: relative;}
#cssmenu ul ul a{
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    padding: 5px 8px 7px 16px;
    display: block;
-webkit-transition: background-color .1s;
   -moz-transition: background-color .1s;
     -o-transition: background-color .1s;
        transition: background-color .1s;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {background-color: #f36f25;}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -16px;
    left: 206px;
    padding: 16px 0 20px 0;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    text-align: left;
    width: 160px;
-webkit-transition: all .3s;
   -moz-transition: all .3s;
     -o-transition: all .3s;
        transition: all .3s;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li:hover > ul { opacity: 1; left: 196px; visibility: visible;}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover{
    background-color: #f36f25;
    color: rgb(240,240,240);
}
```

fiddle is here of the full menu: http://jsfiddle.net/eza2Z/

Also, on the submenu there is a small arrow pointing upwards - how can i change the colour of this to the same colour as the background on the sub menu (#eeeeee)

and 1 more thing :)

When you hover over a link and the sub menu displays, the top and bottom of the sub menu appear about 1-2 seconds after the rest of it for some reason

Help would be much appreciated :)

thanks

Comment: what do you mean by active class?

Comment: so when the page is active it displays a different coloured background

Comment: you cant do it with just css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#cssmenu > ul > li.active {
  /* Add styles for currently "active" list items here */
}
```

If you want the down arrow to have the same background as it's parent you can use the inherit rule on the background property, as so:

```
#myArrow {
  background-color: inherit; /* Will inherit from parent */
}
```

Comment: where is it getting the myArrow div from?

Comment: Well, this is just my example, you'll want to find where the arrow is represented in the HTML and use an appropriate selector to change it's background-color property.